# Which database (DBMS) is approved and recommended for storing WSO2 IOT Server 3.0 metadata?

Tags: wso2, metadata, iot, wso2-iot

Which database (DBMS) is approved and recommended for storing WSO2 IOT Server 3.0 metadata?

Is it recommended to use a database to store WSO2 IOT Server metadata?

Has anyone done this setup? You have already set up a database to store the metadata of the
WSO2 IOT

Answer (score 0):

H2 and MySQL both are well tested and recommended DBMS systems to use with WSO2 IoT Server 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what analyses you want to run on that data. There is no best solution thats beats all others.